# 2-Yr Colleges' Salary Data In College Score Card

Tags: collegescorecard

Using the College Score Card database, does the salary earnings for a 2-yr/community colleges' grad consist of only the students who graduate with a 2-yr degree or less; or does it also include salaries of students who get a 2-yr degree then transfer to a 4-yr university?

Comment: Could you provide a link to this dataset?

Answer (score 1):

Earnings data are based on entry cohorts of students. All students in an entry cohort are included in the earnings calculation for each institution regardless of transfer, completion, and withdrawal events after initial entry at the institution. For more details on how entry cohorts are constructed, see page 30 of the technical paper here: https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/assets/UsingFederalDataToMeasureAndImprovePerformance.pdf